# How or where to override active record timestamp auto handling to use milliseconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I am using a sqlite database setup (requirement to use sqlite) and when I define updated_at and created_at as INTEGER in the schema, I do get integer values stored in those columns automatically from changes to the model which I assume is handled in active record (vs active model).

I want to redefine / patch the method so it uses ms instead of s (i.e. 1384639972645 vs 1384639972). Where is this portion of the code in rails (class/module/method) and how to best approach this?

I am currently using 3.2.11 but would like to know if there is a different answer between 3 and 4 for future planning.

Is this a correct assumption that this conversion of the timestamp to seconds because its defined as INTEGER is happening in active record and not in the sqlite db itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm. Something like this might work:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Timestamp
    def current_time_from_proper_timezone
      self.class.default_timezone == :utc ? (Time.now.utc.to_f*1000).to_i : (Time.now.to_f*1000).to_i
    end
  end
end
```

I might put that in config/initializers/timepatch.rb

Lets give it a try:

```
pry(main)> require 'active_record'
=> true
pry(main)> load 'timepatch.rb'
=> true
pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: 'test.db')
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x40a70
pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Migration.create_table(:kittens){|t| t.string :name; t.timestamps }
-- create_table(:kittens)
   -> 0.1831s
=> {}
pry(main)> class Kitten < ActiveRecord::Base
pry(main)* end  
=> nil
pry(main)> mr_pickles = Kitten.create name: "Mr. Pickles"
=> #<Kitten id: 1, name: "Mr. Pickles", created_at: 1384650727036, updated_at: 1384650727036>
```

I think this is doing what you want, but remember, just because you can doesn't mean you should. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. Looking at your solution and I can see that it seems to get me where I was headed but I am wondering if I can push this a little farther downstream from this method and closer to where the current implementation is converting a Time object to an  Integer object now. This method current_time_from_proper_timezone, without modification, is returning a Time object and I currently get an Integer in my column, when the column type is defined as INTEGER so somewhere between that method and the database write, its getting converted to an INTEGER. Also, what is your concern?

Comment: My concern with something like this is that the consequences of monkeypatching a fundamental method of AR, dealing with a fundamental thing like time (altering every piece of data you will collect), is likely to end in pain at some point. Future requirements to do with date math, outgrowing sqlite maybe, I don't know how, or when, but my gut feeling is to assume something like this would end in tears. The specifics of your project might mean that my concerns are unfounded. Its not to surprising that AR would cast the date to a type that fits the actual column type.

Comment: If I use your above example, I would wrap it in a conditional block only for the models where I need this. I would like to see if I can push this farther downstream however and possibly even into a function in the sqlite database itself so that the casting, conversion occurs there. Haven't yet figured out where / how that might occur.